# Only show specific button onclick, remaining should be the same

Tags: angular, typescript

When I click on confirm button the specific button 
need to be changed to **request sent**.

But remaining should be as **JOIN RIDE** button but it is getting disabled. Can any one help me with this?

Please check the [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/8PypLpWxYABmeJVqAXTL/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the same variable to hide the confirmation panel for all the items. To correct this, you can do the following:

---

> You can create a class to store the ride requests:

```
export class RideRequest{
  constructor(city:string){
    this.city = city;
  }
  city: string;
  requestSent:boolean;
  requestConfirmed:boolean;
  joinRequested:boolean;
}
```

> Modify you App class to the following:

```
export class App {

  rideRequests:RideRequest;

  constructor() { 
      this.rideRequests = [{'city':'Hyderabad'},
                           {'city':'Banglore'},
                           {'city':'New Delhi'},
                           {'city':'Mumbai'},
                           {'city':'Gujrat'},
                           {'city':'Pune'}];
   }

  joinRequested(ride:RideRequest) {
    ride.joinRequested = true;
    console.log(ride);
  }
  confirmRide(ride:RideRequest) {
    ride.requestConfirmed = true;
    console.log(ride);
  }
  cancelRide(ride:RideRequest) {
    ride.joinRequested = false;
    ride.requestConfirmed = false;
    console.log(ride);
  }
}
```

> Then, modify your component template to the following:

```
<div>
  <div class="conform">
    Select one city:

    <div class="details" *ngFor="let ride of rideRequests;let i = index">
      <hr />
      <p>{{ride.city}}</p>
       <div *ngIf="!ride.joinRequested && !ride.requestConfirmed">
        <button (click)="joinRequested(ride)" class="joinRide">JOIN RIDE</button>
      </div>
      <div  class="dialogBoxStyle" *ngIf="ride.joinRequested && !ride.requestConfirmed">
        <p>Your Pickup Time: 8:30AM </p>
        <p>
          <button (click)="cancelRide(ride)">Cancel</button>
          <button (click)="confirmRide(ride)">Confirm</button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="ride.requestConfirmed">
        <button class="joinRide reqSents" (click)="Requestclick(ride)">
           Request Sent
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is a link to the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hYF0BuFeRo07Vr4nn2u4?p=preview

Comment: Its working fine but i wanted to use bulk data like i will not end my data only with two options (hyderabad/banglore)every time i cant push the data so can u please suggest me how can i do using index so that i can display only particulur div button

Comment: You dont need the index approach. I suppose that you will get the bulk data as json. You can assign that json to your reideRequests. See the updated answer and plunker link.

Comment: I have modified the plunk as per your need.

Comment: I have upvoted but my repuation is less than 15 so its not displaying Thnx for your help